# Do we need to modify .sh file while executing in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I have one .sh file which runs well on MAC system. I want to run the same .sh file on windows using CYGWIN. My question is, Do I need to make any modification in the commands while using it in Windows system with CYGWIN? Please help.

e.g. I have the following commands in .sh file-

```
export ML_SERIALIZE_DIR=/Users/Mxyz/ML

export ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH=true

echo ML_SERIALIZE_DIR = $ML_SERIALIZE_DIR

echo ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH = $ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH 

java -DCL_LOG_DIR="/Users/Mxyz/ML" -classpath .:lib/:Ml-mobxyz-import.jar org.xy.mobxyz.mobxyz.ML

echo "Batch program is complete"
```

Comment: It depends on what the script does: what directories and files it tries to access, what external commands it executes.

Comment: I have added few commands in my question. Does it need any modification while executing with Cygwin?

Answer (score 2):

No need to change anything but make sure that all required binaries by your .sh must be there in CYGWIN

Comment: Can you please explain a bit about the binaries? The commands that my .sh file mainly contains are for export, echo and java.

Comment: Linux binaries like export,echo,sh,cd,mkdir,ls,ps but don't worry CYGWIN have all this necessary binaries but you need to give path of java installation as you are using java in shell script

Comment: I have added the commands which are very similar to my actual .sh script. Do I need any modification in it or it can run in it's raw form?